# How to make contourf plot based on points boundary?

Tags: python, plot

I have a csv file including lan, lon, z values. I've been trying to make contourf based on bellow code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import geojsoncontour
import utm
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import alphashape
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from mask import alpha_shape
import math
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

data_url = 'http://spatialcloud.ir/files/data_1.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data_url)
df.head()

x,y  = utm.to_latlon(df.lat, df.lon, 39, 'N')
z = df.z

plt.scatter(y,x)

def plot_contour(x,y,z,resolution = 50,contour_method='linear'):
    resolution = str(resolution)+'j'
    X,Y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):complex(resolution),   min(y):max(y):complex(resolution)]
    points = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(x,y)]
    Z = griddata(points, z, (X, Y), method=contour_method)
    return X,Y,Z

X,Y,Z = plot_contour(y,x,z,resolution = 50,contour_method='linear')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,8))
cpf = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z,cmap="rainbow")
fig.colorbar(cpf)
plt.show()
```

The result is like the below image : [image: contourf image] But I need to make contourf based on my points boundary like this : [image: my desire result] what I want from contourf I mean I need to make contourf just inside the black polygon which is my points boundray and all colors outside of black polygon get removed. What should I do???

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same question.

Comment: The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082717/limit-mask-matplotlib-contour-to-data-area/63442103#63442103) question helped me.